# Laravel column summation

Tags: laravel, eloquent, sum, relationship

I have this query 
`$installments = Installment::where('merchant_id',1)->with('bills')->get();` .

and I need to get `sum()` of `bill_amount` column where exists in `bills` tables .
I have tried this in **controller**:

```
$paid_amount = 0;
$not_paid_amount = 0 ;
 foreach ($installments as $installment) {
        $paid_amount += $installment->bills->where('status',1)->sum('bill_amount');
        $not_paid_amount += $installment->bills->where('status',0)->sum('bill_amount');
    }
```

this work but I think it's not best practices,
**What is the best way to do that?** 
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I think you can better have a view in DB combining the two tables and does the summation and then select from the view.

you create in DB something like :(needs to be tweaked as per ur tables)

```
CREATE or replace VIEW `merchatnt_bills` AS select sum(`bill`.`bill_amount`),`mr`.`merchant_id` AS `merchant_id`
 from ((`merchant` `mr`, `bills` `bill`) join `farms` `f`) where ((<put one to many relatuion between two tables>) and (<any other condition u like>)
group by <columns>)
```

Comment: can you explain that,please?

Comment: then after created the view in DB , create a model object in Laravel , and select from it it the same way you select from table